# QApplication Crashing on Constructor call

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-code, cmake, qt5

I have a very basic QT application. Using QT 5.9.1.

At the very first line in my main method:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
}
```

My call to the QApplication constructor crashes.

I've tried to launch this in a gdb debugger within VS Code, however because I don't have 'QApplication.cpp', I can't step through the constructor call. I can't really find any other backtrace information. If I just launch GDB in the terminal, I can't get the application to see Windows platform DLLs

Is there any otherway to debug this? I can't see why this is happening, but I am out of ideas... i

Comment: add the error you get

Comment: @DanielNudelman problem is i don't get an error.. or have anyway of seeing it.. it just crashes :/

Comment: Maybe you don't have the platforms or plugins folders in your binary directory. Although in this case you should get a popup dialog.

Comment: Maybe what I will say is wrong, but if you actually `return a.exec()` is it still crashing?

Answer (score 1):

You might have a plugin problem, or other installation issue.  Define this environment variable at runtime (in the terminal).

```
$ QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 ./myapp
```

If this doesn't provide anything useful, you might try running your application under `strace`, so you can see which files it is attempting to access, and if there is any suspicious system call that provides a hint:

```
$ strace ./myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

This same code works for me.

Could I suggest you to try a complete minimal example?

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    return a.exec();
}
```

If this does not work, reinstalling the Qt library seem the most obvious way to troubleshot. Maybe some missmatch between headers and/or libs.

Comment: ugh. I guess that might be my next step.. that does not work!